# Hybris sap use Spring?

Tags: spring, sap-commerce-cloud

I all,

I have experience with oracle atg and now i want to merge to hybris sap, so i have some questions about hybris.

For development, does hybris uses spring, that means when i develop an hybris application do i use spring ioc, spring mvc and spring security (@autowired, @controller, @service...) or just like atg the usage of spring is done in the background and when i use angular with hybris do i have to use spring (@RESTController) and for data access do i have to use hibernate or does it have his own methods? And do we have to use spring boot and spring data with it?

Answer (score 4):

I haven't got knowledge about oracle ATG. Hybris is a platform which has a lot of module. Some modules developed with spring (xml based config), for example web services and customer ui (store front). Hybris has own ORM, so spring data not used. Hybris using a lot of technologies, some of them:

- Spring
- Apache Solr
- ZK Framework
- Apache Ant
- Apache Tomcat
- Junit
- JQuery

Also we use a lot of languages for this technologies:

- Html
- Java
- Javascript
- Flex Query
- Bean shell
- Groovy
- Jsp
- Lucene
- Cron

You can use other frameworks look like React for store front with developing custom controls. But hybris has a lot of out of the box functions for managing ui and customization on the fly. These functionalities may be not usable with different framework or it needs a lot of work.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about ATG, but in hybris there are many modules using which you can quickly setup a live production website within 4-6 months.

**Front-End:**

- JSP, JSTL, EL
- Javascript, HTML, CSS
- Bootstrap
- jQuery

---

**Backend:**

- Java for handling and writing the logic
- Spring Core, Spring MVC, Spring Security
- Spring EL

---

**Database**:

More than 6 databases are supported:
- SAP
- HANA
- HSQLDB
- MySQL
- SQL Server
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL and many are added

---

**For searching:**

Hybris has its own search engine.

**Lucene, Apache Solr**

Now you can use Google cloud search as well.

---

**For scripting:**

- beanshell
- JavaScript
- Groovy

Answer (score 0):

Please keep an eye on the Hybris Commerce roadmap. Thin Angular.JS based UI is probably the future.

UI development is typically done in Hybris Commerce using the Hybris Commerce WCMS framework, and extending or creating new pages, widgets, etc. The stuff provided out-of-the-box in accelerators and extensions is very feature rich. Angular is already in there, if you know where to look.

Hybris Commerce also provides OCC (Omni Commerce Connect) REST API extension. REST endpoints are automatically generated at compile time. This is very mature, and has been the primary integration strategy for native mobile commerce apps and separate digital asset management (DAM) tools.

More ideas:
https://hybrismart.com/2016/09/03/angularjs-v-2-and-hybris/

Answer (score 0):

The basis of Hybris is mostly spring mvc, so yes, you can use spring mvc annotations for mapping, mostly all the code in hybris is done using the spring standard, including autowiring, annotations and xml files.
Unlike ATG where you have formhandlers, droplets etc to deal with UI and backend connection, Hybris uses the facade design pattern. That is,

- You have a facade layer that acts as a sort of barrier between your request handling logic and your service logic.
- Therefore, variables used in the service layer (Model Objects) are not carried forward to the request handling layer and separate variables are used (Data Objects)

Regarding database, Hybris has its own ORM, and they are called as Models and items, the concept is similar to repositories in ATG. For example, to create a new item entry, add the same to an items.xml file, providing the name of the model, the table used for persisting and the various attributes (corresponding to the fields in the table). So when you run ant  all for building your application, Hybris uses this mapping to create a model class for your item, this is basically a pojo class, that has getters and setters for all your attributes. So if you save a model object, you will be persisting the data in the database.

To query the data, there is a special query language called as flexible search,it is nearly same as sql but with a few syntax differences, so instead of querying tables, you query items, much like using RQL in ATG.
You can also access data using model objects.

Relations too can be created using items.

Hope this gives you a more clearer picture.

Answer (score 0):

to Start with Hybris, you need to be good at java,jsp,html,css.
And framework such as Spring and Hibernate.
Last but not the least:you should good in any Query language,which helps you lot while coding in Hybris, because hybris have there own language called as **Flexible Search Query**.